# At what position in the stack should the preserved registers be saved when calling a function?

Tags: assembly, x86

Depending on the calling convention, when calling a function, the caller must preserve some registers and the callee must preserve the other registers.

Now I am trying to understand at what position in the stack should the preserved registers be saved.

This is what I think is the correct position:

[image]

Comment: If your function isn't re-entrant, you could even save them in `static` storage somewhere.  (You could, but don't.  There's no advantage, I just point it out to reinforce the point that your function owns the stack space above the args, and there's no requirement on *how* you arrange to return with call-preserved registers holding their original values..)

Answer (score 4):

The term "caller-saved registers" doesn't mean that the caller *must* save them; it means that the caller can't count on them to have any reasonable value after a call, so *if the caller cares about the values* it must save them.

The caller might decide to save all, some, or none of the caller-save registers. Therefore, they have to go *before* anything that's part of the actual function call process (the arguments and return address).

Similarly, the callee doesn't *need* to store the `ebp` or the callee-save registers; it just needs to make sure they have the same value on return. If it never uses them, then there's no reason to save them.

The only truly immutable parts of the calling convention are the arguments, return address, which registers are callee-save, and how values are returned. Those define how one function interacts with another, and if you change that nobody will know how to call your function/the called function won't know what it needs to. For everything else, a compiler can and probably will do whatever it finds convenient, and so can you.

Comment: "call-preserved" vs. "call-clobbered" is a nice way to avoid the implication that either caller or callee has to save anything.  (And that terminology more clearly  maps to how you actually think about them when allocating regs for things that do or don't need to survive a function call).

Comment: You mentioned args, but caller and callee also have to agree on how values are returned.  Returning a struct by value is handled differently in different ABIs.  For example, some always pass a hidden pointer, but x86-64 System V will pack small structs up to 16 bytes into `rdx:rax`.  And floating-point return values are in `xmm0` in some ABIs, but `st(0)` in other.  Fortunately integer/pointer return values are always in `eax` / `rax` in all calling conventions.  See the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to ABI docs.  Maybe mention return values, or not :P

Comment: @Daniel H @PeterCordes Is "*the callee doesn't need to store the `ebp`*" true? If the callee doesn't need to store the `ebp`, how the callee access its parameters and local variables? It seems that we can't access the parameters given to the function through indirect access such as `[ebp + 8]` because `ebp` would act as base pointer for previous stack frame.

Comment: @rosshjb: The first stack arg is at `[esp+4]` on function entry.  If you `sub esp, 12` to allocate some space for locals, it's at `[esp + 16]` and the space for locals is at `[esp+0]` to `[esp+11]`.  Compilers have no problem keeping track of the correct offset relative to a moving stack pointer, unless the function uses a variable-length array or `alloca` in which case they will use EBP as a frame pointer.  [x86\_64 : is stack frame pointer almost useless?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31417784) (code-size optimization.) / [When should I omit the frame pointer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1942801)